# My HTC Windows Phone isn't charging?

Tags: battery, htc, charging

In the past few days my phone has been very slow to charge. Today I went to charge it while it was dead, and a question mark appeared on the battery icon. The phone kept turning on and off so I took it off the charger and turned it on myself. I then put the phone on the charger, and a red and green light started flashing: red, green, pause... red, green, pause... and then it cuts off, but the phone still won't charge.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Which model of phone is it?

Comment: You should probably have you phone replaced, @Amber.

Comment: Please first check the charger, and then check mobile charger port.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my old HTC 8s. First i thought it's a hardware issue, but after cleaning micro usb port with ear buds and replacing my usb cable the phone started to charge properly. Some devices are sensitive to dust etc. so it's good to clean those ports from time to time.

Comment: Same here: It was happening to me on HTC 8X. Cleaning port and switching cable did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:
1.Remove battery.
2.Get external charger 2amp recommended.
3.Charge it with external charger.
4.Charge for an hour and insert back battery.
5.Check if your phones question mark gone and it can open.
6.If it is opened then try to charge with normal charger.

:) Tell me if this didn worked.

Comment: Welcome to windowsphone.stackexchange.com. For your kind notice, all of your posts will contain your name by default. There is no need to mention it again manually.

Answer (score 0):

Clean USB port. If that doesn't work take an extremely thin screwdrivier and clean out the space between the male plug and the top of the port. The space on my HTC phone had gotten too small (I guess I had bent it somehow), so I used a sliver of a screwdriver to wedge between the top of the port and the male plug and then I moved the screwdriver back and forth to clean it and to increase the space between the USB port and the male plug. Finally, after an hour of failed attempts, success!